# Why does wrapping values in a code block change my typed numbers into Doubles?

Tags: scala

If I call this with 3 I get back an Int-typed return as I expect.

```
  def determineKind( a:Int ):Any = {
    if( a < 5 ) 
      a.toInt
    else if(a<50)
      a.toLong
    else if(a<100)
      a.toFloat
    else
      a.toDouble
  }
```

If I call this with 3, I get back a Double.

```
  def determineKind2( a:Int ):Any = {
    val aResult = { if( a < 5 ) 
      a.toInt  // Execution flows here
    else if(a<50)
      a.toLong
    else if(a<100)
      a.toFloat
    else
      println("Oops!") // Never executed--yet I get a Double back!
      a.toDouble  
    }
    aResult
  }
```

Why?  I don't want the Double.  (The real function uses a match/case block, which also seems to convert any of these numerical types to Double.)

Something about wrapping things in a code block triggers the unwanted type change to Double.

Why is that?

Comment: What are you expecting the type to be?

Comment: `aResult` has the same type as the as the `match` statement.  The `match` statement can return one of `Int`, `Long`, `Float`, or `Double`.  Double is the widest, most general, of the set so that's the result type of the whole expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem lies in how you defined the if block, effectively, in `determineKind2`, `a.toDouble` is always assigned to `aResult` and the entire result of the if block is discarded.

The illustration of what is happening:

```
def block = {
  if(condition)
     v1
  else 
     println(v2)
     v2 
}
```

Always returns v2. This happens because the same code using explicit curly braces would be this:

```
def block = {
  if(condition) {
     v1
  } else {
     println(v2)
  }
     v2 
}
```

Notice how v2 is outside the if block. In case statement block on the other hand:

```
condition match {
  case true => v1
  case _    =>
    println(v2)
    v2
}
```

The same doesn't happen above, the blocks in `case`s are ended by the start of another case in the same scope depth.

As a side note: indentation doesn't have any effect in how blocks are compiled.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky situation where **numeric widening** comes into play. In the first example, you are stating the return type, `Any`, and thus there is no need to widen any of the types. In the second case, `val aResult =` you are asking Scala to infer the type of the if-expression, and it will avoid to infer `Any` and instead decide to widening the individual types numerically to a `Double`. Often this widening is what you'd want, e.g. say you write `Seq(1, 2.3, 4.5)` - you'd expect that to be a `Seq[Double]` and not `Seq[Any]`.

If you define the type of `aResult`, you ask Scala to accept the unspecific type of `Any`:

```
def determineKind(a: Int): Any = {
  val res: Any /* ! */ = if (a < 5)
    a.toInt
  else if (a < 50)
    a.toLong
  else if(a < 100)
    a.toFloat
  else
    a.toDouble

  res
}

assert(determineKind(3).isInstanceOf[Int])
```

---

Numeric widening appears in section 6.26.1 of the [Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html):

> If *e* has a primitive number type which [weakly conforms](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#weak-conformance) to the expected type, it is widened to the expected type using one of the numeric conversion methods `toShort`, `toChar`, `toInt`, `toLong`, `toFloat`, `toDouble` defined [here](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#numeric-value-types).

Comment: I suggest looking closer at the end of the `if`expression in his 2nd method.

Comment: Right, I didn't see that bit

Answer (score 0):

Greg, this block below returns value of type Double because the last thing you do in it is calling toDouble method on a.

```
val aResult = {
    if( a < 5 ) 
      a.toInt  // Execution flows here
    else if(a<50)
      a.toLong
    else if(a<100)
      a.toFloat
    else
      println("Oops!") // Never executed--yet I get a Double back!
      a.toDouble // <---- this line is not a part of if else expression
}
```

That's a good reason why to use curly braces, so you can prevent mistakes like this.